# How to expand accordion based on other button click in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on xamarin forms and I am able to show accordion using through this sample:

> https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1088093/Simple-Accordion-User-Control-in-Xamarin-Forms?msg=5568149#xx5568149xx.

But how to expand accordion Content any other button click for this i have been searching please any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
praveen

Answer (score 0):

You can put all your logic in one method, and then use the different event triggers to call that method:

```cs
private void Handler_Button1Tap(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    ExpandAccordion(s);
}

private void Handler_Button2Tap(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    ExpandAccordion(s);
}

private void ExpandAccordion(object sender)
{
    // Implement whatever method is used to expand the accordion button.
    // Code taken from https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1088093/Simple-Accordion-User-Control-in-Xamarin-Forms
    foreach (var vChildItem in mMainLayout.Children) 
    {
        if (vChildItem.GetType() == typeof(ContentView)) 
        {
            vChildItem.IsVisible = false;
        }

        if (vChildItem.GetType () == typeof(AccordionButton)) 
        {
            var vButton = (AccordionButton)vChildItem;
            vButton.Expand = false;
        }
    }

    var vSenderButton = (AccordionButton)sender;

    // TODO
    // Check which button has been tapped here!! 

    if (vSenderButton.Expand) 
    {
        vSenderButton.Expand = false;
    }
    else vSenderButton.Expand = true;
    vSenderButton.AssosiatedContent.IsVisible = vSenderButton.Expand;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have a button in first accordion content i want to expand second accordian content on button click in the first accordion. How to do it.

Comment: As above, you call the expanding method in the event handler of the button you want to tap on.

Comment: But i have a button inside the ContentView like continue. On click of that button it should open another accordion content. But my Accordion content is separate file menas contentview. We will not get that event handler in accordion class.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

I changed some codes in the sample https://github.com/techierathore/AccordionEx to achieve what you want. And I wrote my explanation by adding code comments below.

First,changes in `CodeEaxmple`:

Add `targetLayout` and `targetBtnList` to each  accordion instance so that they can get each other's `mMainLayout` and `AccordionButton` .

```
  public CodeEaxmple ()
        {
            Title = "Code Example";
            var vAccordionSource = GetSampleData ();
            var vAccordionControl = new Accordion (vAccordionSource);
            var vSecondAccordion = new Accordion (){
                FirstExpaned = true,
                DataSource=GetSampleData ()
            };
            vSecondAccordion.DataBind ();
            var vViewLayout = new StackLayout(){
                Children = {
                    new Label { Text = "First Accordion" },
                    vAccordionControl,
                    new Label { Text = "Second Accordion" },
                    vSecondAccordion}               
            };

            // add targetLayout and targetBtnList to each  Accordion instance
            vAccordionControl.targetLayout = vSecondAccordion.mMainLayout;
            vSecondAccordion.targetLayout = vAccordionControl.mMainLayout;

            vAccordionControl.targetBtnList = vSecondAccordion.btnList;
            vSecondAccordion.targetBtnList = vAccordionControl.btnList;

            Content = vViewLayout;
        }
```

Second, changes in `Accordion.cs`(I only use `targetBtnList[1]` as an example):

```
 public class Accordion : ContentView
        {
            #region Private Variables
            List<AccordionSource> mDataSource;
            bool mFirstExpaned = false;

            #endregion


            //Add targetlayout and targetbtnlist to store the target information which your want to expand.
            public StackLayout mMainLayout;
            public StackLayout targetLayout;

            public List<AccordionButton> btnList;
            public List<AccordionButton> targetBtnList;

            public Accordion ()
            {
                var mMainLayout = new StackLayout ();
                Content = mMainLayout;
            }

            public Accordion (List<AccordionSource> aSource)
            {
                mDataSource = aSource;
                DataBind();
            }

            #region Properties
            public List<AccordionSource> DataSource 
            {   get{ return mDataSource; }
                set{ mDataSource = value; }  }
            public bool FirstExpaned 
            {   get{ return mFirstExpaned; }
                set{ mFirstExpaned = value; }  }
            #endregion

            public void DataBind()
            {
                var vMainLayout = new StackLayout ();
                btnList = new List<AccordionButton> { };
                var vFirst = true;
                if (mDataSource != null) {
                    foreach (var vSingleItem in mDataSource) {

                        var vHeaderButton = new AccordionButton () { Text = vSingleItem.HeaderText, 
                            TextColor = vSingleItem.HeaderTextColor,
                            BackgroundColor = vSingleItem.HeaderBackGroundColor
                        };

                        var vAccordionContent = new ContentView () { 
                            Content = vSingleItem.ContentItems,
                            IsVisible = false
                        };
                        if (vFirst) {
                            vHeaderButton.Expand = mFirstExpaned;
                            vAccordionContent.IsVisible = mFirstExpaned;
                            vFirst = false;
                        } 
                        vHeaderButton.AssosiatedContent = vAccordionContent;
                        vHeaderButton.Clicked += OnAccordionButtonClicked;
                        vMainLayout.Children.Add (vHeaderButton);
                        vMainLayout.Children.Add (vAccordionContent);


                        //store your buttons to use in the expand function
                        btnList.Add(vHeaderButton);
                    }
                }
                mMainLayout = vMainLayout;
                Content = mMainLayout;
            }

            void OnAccordionButtonClicked (object sender, EventArgs args)
            {

                //get the target layout  which you want to expand
                StackLayout temp = targetLayout;

                //get a vSenderButton for which vSenderButton's AssosiatedContent you want to expand
                //here I take targetBtnList[1] as a example, you can sepcify whatever you want to expand
                AccordionButton vSenderButton = targetBtnList[1];

                foreach (var vChildItem in temp.Children) {
                    if (vChildItem.GetType() == typeof(ContentView)) vChildItem.IsVisible = false;
                    if (vChildItem.GetType () == typeof(AccordionButton)) {
                        var vButton = (AccordionButton)vChildItem;

                        if (vButton != vSenderButton)
                        {
                            vButton.Expand = false;
                        }
                    }
                }


                //var vSenderButton = (AccordionButton)sender;
                if (vSenderButton.Expand)
                {
                    vSenderButton.Expand = false;
                }
                else vSenderButton.Expand = true;
                vSenderButton.AssosiatedContent.IsVisible = vSenderButton.Expand;

                //replace the vSenderButton in the targetBtnList to update its Expand property
                targetBtnList[1] = vSenderButton;
            }
```

Launch the app after modify and click the code page to see the changes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try your solution and let you know.

Comment: I am getting exception in this line: AccordionLable vSenderButton = targetBtnList[1]; . Null reference exception in targetBtnList.

Comment: Did you add this line `btnList.Add(vHeaderButton);` in `DataBind`    .Just copy my code to replace your old code.And click the Code Page instead of Xaml Page.

Comment: And it should be `AccordionButton vSenderButton = targetBtnList[1];` instead of `AccordionLable`.